# How can I get the delta from two JSON arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below are two JSON arrays. I want to get delta data (compare the two datasets and return elements that don't appear in both sets).

```
var data1 = [
    { id: 1, name: "Normal" },
    { id: 2, name: "Admin" }
];
var data2 = [
    { id: 1, name: "Normal" },
    { id: 2, name: "Admin" },
    { id: 3, name: "HR" },
    { id: 4, name: "finance" }
];
```

expected output:

```
var Result =  [
    { id: 3, name: "HR" },
    { id: 4, name: "finance" }
];
```

I have tried this but didn't have any luck:

```
$.grep(data2, function (el) { 
    if ($.inArray(el, data1) == -1) 
        diff.push([el, IDl]); 
});
```

Comment: What "various method" have you tried? Please provide your code for what you tried.

Comment: $.grep(data2, function (el) {
    if ($.inArray(el, data1) == -1) diff.push([el, IDl]);
});

Comment: `$.inArray` will always return -1, because it only checks if the objects are referring to the same object in memory, instead of checking if the objects contain the same values. I believe you will need to loop through `data1` and compare their values manually.

Comment: Thanks @forgivenson can i get some form of example

Comment: What do you want to get if your JSON arrays have *this* data:`var data1 = [
    { id: 1, name: "Normal" },
    { id: 2, name: "Admin" }
];
var data2 = [
    { id: 1, name: "Normal" },
    { id: 2, name: "HR" },
    { id: 3, name: "Admin" },
    { id: 4, name: "finance" }
];` (I shifted the position (and id) of "Admin" in the second array).

Comment: There's no JSON there. That's just JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, the problem is you need to do a deep compare of your objects.  inArray will only do a shallow compare.  The following code will do a deep compare by checking equality of `id` and `name`.  Also, it allows jQuery.grep to build the resulting array so you do not need to do this manually.

```js
var data1 = [
    { id: 1, name: "Normal" },
    { id: 2, name: "Admin" }
];
var data2 = [
    { id: 1, name: "Normal" },
    { id: 2, name: "Admin" },
    { id: 3, name: "HR" },
    { id: 4, name: "finance" }
];

function compare(data1, data2) {
  return $.grep(data2, function(el) {
      return !data1.some(function(elToCompare) {
            return elToCompare.id === el.id && elToCompare.name === el.name;
        });
  });
}


$("#output").text(JSON.stringify(compare(data1, data2)));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```